# Xamarin.Forms: better way to implement a control that looks like a ListView on 2 columns

Tags: listview, user-interface, xamarin.forms, multiple-columns, repeater

I'm looking for the better way to implement a control that looks like a **ListView on 2 columns**, where columns have distinct height.

The **excpected result** is something like this:
[image: expected result]

The items of these 2 columns come from the **same DataSource**, and this DataSource can have between 1 and a dozen of items. The items must be splitted automatically (pair/impair), and when the user click on the button related to the item, this must open the item's detail page.

In a first time, I thought about using  the [DLToolkit FlowListView control](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView) , but it seems that the cells of each column must have the same height, so this control can't answer to my needs.

Of course, it's also possible to do this through a Grid, but in this case I should assign each item handly: this doesn't seem to be a good choice.

***Would you have other suggestions? Is there a control allowing to do this?***

Comment: This can be easily implemented. What you need to do is to implement itemtemplate selector. check this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/ .  Develop two datatemplate for odd-even items of listview and then implement templateselector on it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Gaurang. In the FlowListView control, there are ItemTemplateSelectors but it doesn't work as the the second selector inherits the height of the first selector. Are you sure that it could work?

Comment: I never used ItemTemplateSelectors in Xamarin. I used in Windows Phone. Another logical way I got it using Selector is from second item only. Every list item will having a same height and that is fact. But from the second list item, for the second column (grid in list item) you can set top margin of second item and bottom margin of first item in minus numbers to set UI you want. Its bit tricky and  i am suggesting you to play with properties which allow us some freedom. :D

Comment: I don't see how to implement it throuh TemplateSelector and ListView... So I've decided to do it through a Repeater control.